# Modify Invoice Page CSS in Odoo

Tags: jquery, html, css, odoo

I want to change the CSS of Customer Invoice page so that both sections on the right hand side(Top section: invoice and Bottom one: Send a Message) can have scrollbars and visible at the same time.

See the screenshot.
[image]

any ideas which page to edit??

Demo Page or search google for 'odoo demo'.
https://demo1.odoo.com/web/#id=12&view_type=form&model=account.invoice&menu_id=304&action=337

Answer (score 1):

Give `height` to both frame1 and frame2 and give the property `overflow-y:scroll`

Comment: Without getting access to that view, i cant do anything, the link you gave asks to select database.

Comment: try this one https://demo.odoo.com/ or  google 'odoo demo'. it will take you to the direct demo page.

Comment: I cant get to Customer Invoice section. Have you ever used firebug or the inspect tool in browser?

Comment: yes, I tried everything i can but can't figure out from where the page is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the CSS file on the server here..

```
/addons/web/static/src/css/
```

and edited the **base.css** classes in Line no. 1865 and 1937 respectively.

```
.openerp .oe_form_sheetbg
.openerp .oe_form div.oe_chatter
```

Thanks